# Node.js - Passing continuous stream of input to process.stdin

Tags: javascript, node.js, child-process

```
startServer = function(path) {
    console.log("Starting ...");
    server = spawn("java", ["-jar", path], {
        shell: true,
    });
    server.stdin.write("example-input");
    server.stdin.end();
}
```

I have the above (lightly edited) JavaScript, running in Node.js. The stdin input stream for the child process spawned using `spawn()` appears to only be sent once `stdin.end()` is called, at least according to my research. However, my application requires input to be passed to the stream on-demand, which would make calling `.end()` impossible, as far as I know. Is there any workaround for this limitation?

Comment: You might find this useful: https://github.com/TomFrost/FlushWritable

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Force Node.js to flush writes to child processes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17139956/force-node-js-to-flush-writes-to-child-processes)

Answer (score 1):

Keep in mind to write a newline to trigger the flush of a write. So change your code to this:

```js
startServer = function(path) {
    console.log("Starting ...");
    server = spawn("java", ["-jar", path], {
        shell: true,
    });
    server.stdin.write("example-input\n"); // write here also a new line
}
```

This way the stdin will stay open for further writes.